# Port Recycler view created for mobile app to Android TV supporting Dpad controls

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tv, leanback, d-pad

I am currently trying to port Android mobile app to Android TV. I have a RecyclerView that seems to be displaying correctly in my Android TV app. But I don't seem to be able to navigate inside RecyclerView using dpad controls.
P.S i have tried following line.Couldn't find anything else

```
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

Also is it recommended to use recycler view for TV apps ?

Also i have read complete architecture of TV app at developer.android.com and also went through their sample project, But found recycler view nowhere.

Comment: Make recyclerview elements focusable

Comment: I added this line  android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" not working

Comment: The *children* of recycle view must be focusable.

Comment: also added android:focusable="true" to recylerview item. no luck

Comment: It would help if you could provide a code sample of your problem area

Answer (score 0):

As @ULazdins stated, you may try to make your `RecyclerView` focusable. You may refer with this [workaround](https://gist.github.com/vganin/8930b41f55820ec49e4d) for the [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190526&thanks=190526&ts=1445108573) with `RecycleView` focus scrolling when navigating with d-pad.

> As I can see from source the issue is because `GridLayoutManager` uses `LinearLayoutManager`'s implementation of `onFocusSearchFailed()` which is called when focus approaches the inner border of `RecyclerView`. `LinearLayoutManager`'s implementation just offers first/last (depends on scrolling direction) element. Hence focus jumps to first/last element of new row.

Hope this helps!